# Rendering data to ionic view that is null for a moment

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Am loading data from indexedDB using dexie into the info variable.

the problem is the info variable is null for a bit. this makes it not to be rendered in the view.

how do i solve the problem.

below id the code.
home.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import {MyDb} from '../../app/service/core.db';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
   })
     export class HomePage {

         info : any;

         constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private myDb : MyDb) 
         {

         }

         ionViewWillEnter()
        {
           let rec = {first: "Tom", last: "Otasdfile", age : "12"};

           this.myDb.save_contact(rec).then(res => 
            {
            //console.log(res);
            });

           this.myDb.get_contact().toArray(
            data => { 
                this.info = data;
                console.log(this.info); 
                    });
       }
   }
```

home.html

```
   <ion-header>
     <ion-navbar>
       <ion-title>
         Ionic Blank
       </ion-title>
     </ion-navbar>
   </ion-header>

   <ion-content padding>
   <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor = "let i of info">
   {{i.first}} {{i.last}}
   </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   </ion-content>`
```

the view displays the first and last name after navigating to another page and back to the home page. i want the page to render the names as soon as it is loaded

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

use [**safe navigation operator ( ?. )**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) 
While accessing properties of an object it may throw an exception if the object is null or undefined. The Angular safe navigation operator `(?.)` is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths.

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor = "let i of info">
   {{i?.first}} {{i?.last}}
   </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   </ion-content>`
```

Comment: ionic loading controller https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/  from ionic-angular solved the issue